# rails routing: using bound parameter as action name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've been sent a bunch of .html files from a designer and I just want to use them directly, however they have non-resourceful links. I realise that if I map *.html routes to home#* actions, I can start working with his design without changing it.

I tried:

```
get ":page.html", to: "home#%{page}"
```

But it says there's no action %{page}. Is this doable with Rails routes in a single line? Or do I have to make a loop with all the page names?

Note: I'd like a solution without redirection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write something like

```
get ":action.html", controller: 'home'
```

or

```
get ":action.html", defaults: { controller: 'home' }
```

?

Comment: using :action as bound parameter name did it